# MySQL combine 3 queries in to 1

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to combine 3 MySQL queries in to one.

This is what I am using to grab my news entries (with pagination) :

```
SELECT A.sid,
       A.title,
       A.time,
       A.bodytext,
       A.author,
       A.url
FROM news A
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT sid
   FROM news
   WHERE approved=1
   ORDER BY sid DESC LIMIT $start, $limit) B USING (sid)
```

Now, I've recently added a comments feature and would like to get the total amount of comments for each "sid"

The part that gets confusing for me is that I need to match "sid" (from news.news) with "page_id" (from comments.pages) to grab it's unique "id".

```
+----+---------+
| id | page_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |      87 |
|  2 |      86 |
| 41 |      85 |
|  3 |      84 |
| 13 |      83 |
+----+---------+
```

Now with that unique "id", I need to query "comments.comments" and match it with "page_id" column and count(*) how many comments it has - WHERE is_approved = 1

```
SELECT page_id,is_approved,count(*) FROM comments WHERE page_id = $id and is_approved = 1;
+---------+-------------+----------+
| page_id | is_approved | count(*) |
+---------+-------------+----------+
|       1 |           1 |        2 |
+---------+-------------+----------+
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You haven't shown your all the tables.

Comment: modified my post - is that what you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited my response to conform to the updated question:

```
SELECT A.sid, A.title, A.time, A.bodytext, A.author, A.url,
       D.page_id, D.num_comments 
FROM news.news A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT sid 
              FROM news 
             WHERE approved=1 
             ORDER BY sid desc 
             LIMIT $start, $limit) B USING (sid)
LEFT JOIN comments.pages C ON A.sid = C.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT page_id,is_approved,count(*) as num_comments 
             FROM comments.comments 
            WHERE is_approved = 1) D ON C.page_id = D.page_id
```

Comment: it appears the query is missing a step - match "sid" (from news.news) with "page_id" (from comments.pages) to grab the unique ID

Comment: @Mayhem I edited my query with the new information given in the question.

Comment: Thank you - just had to make a small tweak but it works perfectly.